# What's the exact meaning of ～するところ?

Tags: meaning

Here are an example sentence and its translation taken from [an online English-Japanese dictionary](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E6%84%8F%E5%91%B3%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B).

```
問題の意味するところ
the meaning of a question
```

I'm wondering why the example sentence attach するところ and doesn't simply say 問題の意味.

Although there is a grammar that `[verb] + ところ` means `is about to [verb]`, that grammar can't seem to be applied at here.

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2968/7810, http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23738/7810, http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32683/7810, http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24759/7810, http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6517/7810, http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21795/7810

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ところ has many meanings. This ところ means "thing, content". http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/158611/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D/

So 問題の意味するところ is same as 問題の意味すること. Of course, 問題の意味 make sense but if 問題の意味する, the word like こと or ところ is needed because 問題の意味する is a modification phrase so a modified word is needed like that.

It is probably "what a question means" in English.

Comment: So it looks like the するところ at here does not mean anything special. I guess the author of the example sentence was just bored and added the redundant するところ in order to kill some time.